# Fazer um " ou " dentro da chave de um atributo em JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
scope.cm = 1;
scope.mm = 2;
scope.km = 3;


    tipoDeMedida[scope.cm || scope.mm || scope.km] = function(arrayQualquer){
          //executo meu bloco de código X.
    }

    tipoDeMedida[scope.km](arrayQualquer)
```

Estou recebendo a seguinte saida de erro:

```
    tipoDeMedida[scope.km] is not a function
```

Pelo que eu entendi, na função do primeiro bloco de código, não está aceitando o operador OU para cada tipo de dado que estou tentando passar. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma elegante de resolver esse problema, sem ter que fazer uma função para cada tipo de dado(não quero executar o bloco X três vezes).

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que quer fazer, mas se tu fizer `var tipoMedida = function(tipo, arrayQualquer)` e passar como `tipoMedida(scope.km, arrayQualquer)` não resolve?

Comment: Resolve sim... Vou fazer isso inclusive. Só perguntei porque o padrão do sistema em questão é esse que eu mostrei, dai vai ter que refatorar muita coisa nessa sua solução.Mas eu queria entender o porque que ele não tá reconhecendo os outros valores....

Comment: Ah, sim, não funciona porque `||`(ou) é boolean, é 1, 2 ou 3, e outras linguagens isso geraria um `true`, mas pelo que vi o js tende a usar só o primeiro valor informado, possivelmente você teria só o do **cm**

Comment: entendi... Você está certo! Testei aqui e é exatamente isso que está acontecendo. O valor de scope.cm sempre vai existir, logo nunca vai cair na próxima condição....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso não funciona pelo seguinte motivo

- Ao avaliar a expressão `[scope.cm || scope.mm || scope.km]`, o primeiro valor é considerado válido, então os outros não são avaliados.

Veja um teste aqui: http://codepen.io/rmagalhaess/pen/bqNVQE?editors=1010

Teria que fazer para cada valor, como no código abaixo.

```
<div id="painel"> </div>
<hr>
<div id="funcoes"> </div>

<script>
    function Exibir( p_Param )
    {
        var painel = document.getElementById('painel');
        painel.innerHTML += p_Param+'<br>';
    }

    var mm = 1, cm = 2, dm = 3;
    var Medida = [];
    Medida[mm] = function( p_Param ){ Exibir('Medida: '+p_Param); }
    Medida[cm] = function( p_Param ){ Exibir('Medida: '+p_Param); }
    Medida[dm] = function( p_Param ){ Exibir('Medida: '+p_Param); }
    Medida[cm](cm);

    var g = 1, k = 2, t = 3, x = 4, y = 5;
    var Peso = [];
    Peso[ g || m || t || x || y ] = function( p_Param ){ Exibir('Peso: '+p_Param); }
    Peso[g](x);

    var funcoes = document.getElementById('funcoes');
    funcoes.innerHTML += 'Medida[cm] '+typeof(Medida[cm])+'<hr>';
    funcoes.innerHTML += 'Peso[g] '+typeof(Peso[g])+'<hr>';
    funcoes.innerHTML += 'Peso[m] '+typeof(Peso[m]); // Não executa
</script>
```

---

O resultado é:

```
Medida: 2  
Peso: 4  
Medida[cm] function  
Peso[g] function
```